# Frustrating "NetworkingError" with Dynamodb local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Downloaded latest version of DynamoDBLocal from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html). Always I receive the following error.

{"code":"NetworkingError","name":"NetworkingError","retryable":true}

```
    { [NetworkingError: Connection timed out after 2000ms]
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  name: 'NetworkingError',
  retryable: true,
  statusCode: undefined,
  requestId: undefined }
{"TableName":"me_change_log_sv0","_batch_write":[],"type":"select","AttributesToGet":["accountid","ts"],"Limit":10}
{ [NetworkingError: Connection timed out after 2000ms]
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  name: 'NetworkingError',
  retryable: true,
  statusCode: undefined,
  requestId: undefined }
```

The version I'm using is:   dynamodb_local_2014-01-08.tar.gz.

Doing the following operations

```
dynamodb.putItem(statement, function (err, data) {
      callback.apply(null, [err, data]);
});

dynamodb.query(statement, function (err, data) {
      callback.apply(null, [err, data]);
});
```

AWS SDK Im using

```
{
  "name": "aws-sdk",
  "description": "AWS SDK for JavaScript",
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "author": {
    "name": "Amazon Web Services",
    "url": "http://aws.amazon.com/"
  }
....
}
```

Size of the data-base file just not even 5MB yet.

```
**strace -p 11938**

Process 11938 attached - interrupt to quit
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58641, 454709654}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 251)            = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58641, 706940918}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58641, 707751761}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179396, 424759}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179396, 425586}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179396, 426742}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58641, 711884239}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58641, 712370018}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 395)            = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 108247170}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 108496768}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179396, 824674}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 111188119}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 111376226}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179396, 827532}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
gettimeofday({13Size of the data-base file just not even 5MB yet.
94179396, 828122}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 112405642}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 112589276}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 1999) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 113063596}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179396, 829495}, NULL) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 115065409}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1998) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 115448331}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [17179869184], [4]) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179396, 831619}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179396, 831712}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58642, 117816574}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179396, 833886}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 120194689}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 120410187}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179398, 836592}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179398, 836925}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179398, 837449}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 121921190}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 122087215}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 798)            = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 921361600}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 921663465}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179399, 638704}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
gettimeofday({1394179399, 640843}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 0) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 925632992}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179399, 642726}, NULL) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 929255653}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1996) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 929582115}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [73014444032], [4]) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179399, 646078}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179399, 646709}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58644, 937373310}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179399, 653452}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58646, 940676861}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58646, 940782793}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179401, 656963}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 657395}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 657951}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658118}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658335}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658414}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658566}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658645}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179401, 658740}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58646, 943174515}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58646, 943388057}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 1597)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 542456984}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 542703227}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179403, 259293}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
gettimeofday({1394179403, 262747}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 0) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 548806493}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179403, 265866}, NULL) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 553015277}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1995) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 553498821}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [73014444032], [4]) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179403, 269696}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179403, 269834}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58648, 554508951}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179403, 270592}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58650, 557769458}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58650, 557991944}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179405, 274435}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 275305}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 275666}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 276198}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 277094}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 277750}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 278327}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 279071}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179405, 280566}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 281143}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 281282}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 282023}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 282423}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179405, 282753}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179405, 284865}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58650, 569868662}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58650, 570084720}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 3187)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 758444376}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 758737017}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 476156}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 8)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 769439255}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 769746431}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 486295}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 490406}, NULL) = 0
mmap(0x355236d16000, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x355236d16000
munmap(0x355236d16000, 958464)          = 0
munmap(0x355236f00000, 90112)           = 0
mmap(0x355236e00000, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x355236e00000
gettimeofday({1394179408, 494454}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 494650}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 495535}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 495640}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 495927}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 496669}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 0) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 780950938}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 498885}, NULL) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 785151335}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1995) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 785680158}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [73014444032], [4]) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179408, 502416}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 502605}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58653, 789911863}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179408, 505975}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58655, 792847586}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58655, 793199203}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179410, 510503}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 510881}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 511483}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 511886}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 512321}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 512587}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 512769}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 513575}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179410, 515897}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 516224}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 516972}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 517641}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 517850}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179410, 518122}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179410, 519480}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58655, 804035602}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58655, 804501257}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 6389)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 198666141}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 198872416}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179416, 915474}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 4)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 204102508}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 204565089}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179416, 921353}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 922707}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 923319}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 923405}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 924451}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 925112}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 925758}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
gettimeofday({1394179416, 930442}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 0) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 214918224}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179416, 932895}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 933175}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 934451}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 935330}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 936345}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 936668}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 937040}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 222878802}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1992) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 223508526}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [73014444032], [4]) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179416, 940742}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 941150}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58662, 229745675}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179416, 945801}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58664, 232432080}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58664, 232682516}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179418, 949109}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179418, 949571}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179418, 950540}, NULL) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58664, 235647782}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58664, 236081853}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 12796)          = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 43409839}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 43672853}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e000Size of the data-base file just not even 5MB yet.08c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179431, 760324}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
gettimeofday({1394179431, 763377}, NULL) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1024, 0) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 47951511}) = 0
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179431, 765289}, NULL) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 10
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 50796311}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 1997) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 51254978}) = 0
getsockopt(10, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [73014444032], [4]) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179431, 767687}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179431, 768015}, NULL) = 0
write(10, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws"..., 628) = 628
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58677, 52785266}) = 0
gettimeofday({1394179431, 768842}, NULL) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 10, {EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 2000)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58679, 55059403}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58679, 55168410}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1394179433, 771420}, NULL) = 0
write(1, "undefined\n", 10)             = 10
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f30e00008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(1, "{ [NetworkingError: Connection t"..., 178) = 178
write(1, "{\"TableName\":\"webyog_change_log_"..., 129) = 129
write(1, "{ [NetworkingError: Connection t"..., 178) = 178
write(1, "null\n", 5)                   = 5
close(10)                               = 0
epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 0)              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {58679, 59887568}) = 0
futex(0x7f30e676b9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 11939, NULL) = 0
mmap(0x2f54f5b00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2f54f5b00000
munmap(0x7f30e66da000, 528384)          = 0
munmap(0x3957a6000000, 33554432)        = 0
munmap(0x38a94da00000, 544768)          = 0
munmap(0xc8e5f100000, 1048576)          = 0
munmap(0x20806de00000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0xefb91a00000, 1048576)          = 0
munmap(0x1eb3e7b00000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x355236e00000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x1d38a6900000, 217088)          = 0
munmap(0x11fdb5a00000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x390bcb700000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x36c1e6f00000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x2b516a800000, 1048576)         = 0
mmap(0x2f54f5a00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2f54f5a00000
mmap(0x2f54f5c00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2f54f5c00000
munmap(0x202a98400000, 151552)          = 0
munmap(0x10f20e500000, 1048576)         = 0
munmap(0x1949a5400000, 151552)          = 0
munmap(0x2a62a9f9f000, 393216)          = 0
munmap(0x102d2b8f000, 2097152)          = 0
munmap(0x2ce787b07000, 4194304)         = 0
munmap(0x2f54f59e6000, 536870912)       = 0
futex(0xe8a104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xe8a100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xe8a140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
munmap(0x7f30e675b000, 69632)           = 0
munmap(0x7f30e47ff000, 10489856)        = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 11938 detached
```

I'm not able to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Did you mention the port number of the dynamo as well (default 8000) in the connection? After starting the Dynamo local, when you connect the ip address (mostly localhost) and port number also need to be provided.

Comment: How are you creating the DynamoDB object? That would be more important than seeing the putObject calls. Also do you have any logs from DynamoDB Local?

Comment: Also I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of the SDK, 1.18.0, with many more features and bug fixes.

Comment: Did you mention the port number of the dynamo as well (default 8000) in the connection? I'm running in a different port. http://localhost:8999. dynamodb.putItem works but some of them are failing. dynamodb.Query is always failing due to time out.

Comment: Following the same example as its documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html

Comment: Sure @Sony Kadavan I will try upgrading the latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score -1):

"NetworkingError" is just an occasional error returned by dynamoDb from time to time, it's probably not related to your code at all... try the same command later, and it might auto-magically work next time...